# Open a HTML-File in a Browser via Java

Tags: java, browser, desktop

I want to open an HTML file in a browser via Java. I've already found this way:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse( new URI("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
```

Now, I don't want to start the standard browser from the user, my goal is to start a portable browser from the USB. Somthing like firefox or chrome from this website: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet
Do you have an idea what's the best way to do this?

Comment: "My goal is to start a mobile App browser from the USB." you nearly couldn't be more unspecific.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant a portable browser. Something you can find here:

Comment: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet - it doesn't matter if it's firefox or chrome

Answer (score 0):

The browser you want to use is environment-specific (OS, architecture...). That's not really the Java philosophy because you would have to produce patform-specific code.

In JavaFX, you got an [embedded Webkit browser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).